# How to delete a default snippet in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets

I created a new snippet (my Function) that clashes with a default snippet (Function). I've searched for a snippet file in the default location with the contents `<description>Function</description>` but I can't find it anywhere in the ST3 folder (I have no problem finding the file that contains `<description>my Function</description>`).

I think I deleted the file that contained the default snippet at some point, is it possible this is still stored in a cache file? How can I get rid of it?

[image]